# ImageMagick - Convert multipage pdf to animated gif

Tags: pdf, macports, file-conversion

I have a two-page PDF file that I would like to convert to an animated GIF file.  A [post on the TeX StackExchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23728/1402) gives the following ImageMagick one-liner:

```
convert -verbose -delay 50 -loop 0 -density 300 file.pdf file.gif
```

If I try this on a linux box (`convert --version` gives 6.5.4-7 2012-04-10) I get this log:

```
"gs" -q -dQUIET -dPARANOIDSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=0 "-sDEVICE=pnmraw" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 "-r300x300"  "-sOutputFile=/tmp/magick-XX30a4nG" "-f/tmp/magick-XX690OkA" "-f/tmp/magick-XX3GCKhu"
/tmp/magick-XX30a4nG[0] PNM 1512x1134 1512x1134+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 9.811mb
/tmp/magick-XX30a4nG[1] PNM 1512x1134 1512x1134+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 9.811mb
file.pdf[0] PDF 1512x1134 1512x1134+0+0 16-bit DirectClass 9.811mb
file.pdf[0] PDF 1512x1134 1512x1134+0+0 16-bit DirectClass 9.811mb
file.pdf=>file-linux.gif[0] PDF 1512x1134 1512x1134+0+0 16-bit Palette PseudoClass 111c 2.620u 0:03
```

[`gs` is GPL Ghostscript 8.70 (2009-07-31)] and it works as expected.  But if I try this on my mac, using the ImageMagick suite installed by macports (6.8.0-7 2013-01-04), I get this log:

```
"/opt/local/bin/gsx" -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=pngalpha" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 "-r300x300"  "-sOutputFile=/var/folders/kf/t7750q1w8xjcjy0059bpyx180000gq/T/magick-15750GLLaATgky5I1" "-f/var/folders/kf/t7750q1w8xjcjy0059bpyx180000gq/T/magick-15750ljasKifrwJcW" "-f/var/folders/kf/t7750q1w8xjcjy0059bpyx180000gq/T/magick-15750w8mj9AZrkJA8"
/var/folders/kf/t7750q1w8xjcjy0059bpyx180000gq/T/magick-15750GLLaATgky5I1 PNG 1512x1134 1512x1134+0+0 8-bit sRGB 64.5KB 0.050u 0:00.049
file.pdf PDF 1512x1134 1512x1134+0+0 16-bit sRGB 64.5KB 0.000u 0:00.000
file.pdf=>file.gif PDF 1512x1134 1512x1134+0+0 16-bit Palette sRGB 106c 0.410u 0:00.409
```

[`/opt/local/bin/gsx` is GPL GhostScript 9.06 (2012-08-08)]
This time the resulting GIF file has only one frame, the first page of the PDF.

My workaround so far has been to use `pdftk file.pdf burst` to split out each page of the PDF to its own file, then `convert [options] pg_*.pdf file.gif`.  This works fine, but I'd prefer a one-line script.

The mac versions being more recent, I would guess it's a matter of implementation.  The only major difference I see between the two is `-sDEVICE=pnmraw` for the linux version and `-sDEVICE=pngalpha` for the mac.  Can I tell `convert` to pass options to `gsx`?

Comment: YES ? :), but to be honest, why dont you just try it!

Comment: @Borderline: I tried adding `-sDEVICE=pnmraw` to the `convert` command line options and got an "unrecognized option" response.

Comment: Why not combine both commands into a single line command?

`pdftk file.pdf burst && convert [options pg_*.pdf file.gif`

This way, Terminal will run the second command once it has completed the first command you requested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following command worked well for me from a paper PDF I've worked on. The only difference from your original command is deactivating the alpha channel:

```
convert -alpha deactivate -verbose -delay 50 -loop 0 -density 300 paper.pdf file.gif
```

I'm using `Version: ImageMagick 6.8.3-3 2013-02-21 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org` and homebrew.